# random out picture with its related text

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

Good day! I want to random out picture in path then it have a picture. I am currently working on my game homework. It is a guessing game which users will guess a word I would like to give a clue to users using picture and sometimes descriptions, how will i get the picture together with its related word. I have already declare the guess word in a string and I randomize it.

```
string[] movie = { "avengers",
    "deadpool",
    "titanic",
    "thenotebook",
    "IronMan",
    "HarryPotter",
    "LordoftheRings",
    "HungerGames"};


string word = sports[r.Next(0, words.Length)].ToUpper();
                Array.ForEach(this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray(), lbl => lbl.Dispose());
                Array.ForEach(alphabetButtons, b => b.Enabled = true);
                labels = new List<Label>();
                int startX = 14;
```

and Idon't know what is the next step i will make.

Comment: Having some trouble understanding exactly what you are trying to do here, but look at using a Dictionary in C#.  Each entry in a dictionary has a KEY and a VALUE.  Both these KEY and VALUE entries can be objects themselves.

Comment: thanks sir Jay for the info